# Change date column according to time column in Excel

Tags: vba, date, time, excel

I have been facing a problem for some time now with my Excel macro and I have not been able to find a solution anywhere. What I want to do is described below:

I have an Excel sheet that includes the EPG information of a TV channel for the current month.
One column includes the names of the TV programs/events. Next to it, another column that includes the corresponding start time of each TV program (e.g. 13:15) and a third column that  includes the corresponding date of each event (20/07/2012).

The problem is that the day does not change after 00:00 as it should but it changes at 06:00 in the morning instead. I want a macro that searches the whole time column, find any time that is between 00:00 06:00 and go to the corresponding date cell and change the date (add one day). Is that possible, and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need VBA. Insert a column just after your date column. I'm assuming now that your times are in column B and your dates are in column C. now in your new column D put the formula

```
=IF(AND(B1 >= 00:00 and B1 < 06:00), C1 + 1, C1)
```

Then you can hide column C if you like. And change the number format of column D to be a date. I'm not 100% sure on the syntax for comparing a time though, i.e. the `A1 >= 00:00` but according to this thread: http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=212849 it should be

```
=IF(AND(B1 >= TIME(0,0,0) and B1 < TIME(6,0,0), C1 + 1, C1)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan for your reply , it helped me a lot. What worked for me was the following :on column D   =IF(AND(B1 >= TIME(0,0,0), B1 < TIME(6,0,0)), SUM(DATEVALUE(C2),1), C2) . Then I used that in my macro :  Columns("D:D").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC[-2] >= TIME(0,0,0), RC[-2] < TIME(6,0,0)), SUM(DATEVALUE(RC[-1]),1), RC[-1])"

Comment: Glad it helped, do you really need the macro though? Can't you just type that formula in the cell and drag down?

Comment: Well this is just one function of my macro. Thanks again.